# React Router: Route defined in child component is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In main component i use switch

```
function Router(props) {

    return (<main>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/prices/'
                   render={(props) => <PricesPage {...props} />}
            />
            <Route path="/prices/add/"
                   render={(props) => <PriceGroupAddFormConnected {...props}/>}
            />
        </Switch>
    </main>) 
}
```

And in one of PricesPage children i define route to render a dialog

PricesPage:

```
function PricesPage(props) {

    return (<Child/>) 
}
```

Child:

```
function Child(props) {

    return (
            <><Route exact path="/prices/dialog" component={Dialog}/>
            <Child1/></>)
        )

}
```

And in child1 i define a Link.

Child1:

```
function Child1(props) {

    return (
            <Link to="/prices/dialog"/>)
        )

}
```

Expected: when link changed -> dialog is opened

Current: link changed, but dialog is'not opening. But then i define route in main component, it works, however i need to keep other children components under dialog, so it is not enough

Answer (score 0):

When you hit `/prices/`, your route `/prices/dialog` is created because it's in a child component of `<PricesPage>`. But, when you go to `/prices/dialog`, your route `/prices/dialog` is unload because `/prices/dialog` don't match exactly `/prices/` neither than `/prices/add/`.

You have 2 options:

1. Remove the `exact` key on `<Route path='/prices/' render={(props) => <PricesPage {...props} />}`. So when you hit `/prices/dialog`, you'll have both `/prices/` component and `/prices/dialog` component rendered (same for `/prices/add/`)
2. Add your route `/prices/dialog` in your Router aside your other routes `/prices/` and `/prices/add/`

I recommend the 2nd one if you need separate render and 1st one if you can have multiple render at the same time.